# How to fix the kernel detection problem in vs code

Tags: python, visual-studio, jupyter-notebook

I am a python newbie. I have a problem with VS code. As shown below, my vs code is always detecting the kernel. And I cannot execute any code. Please help me

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKBcF.png)

I want to select kernel, but there is no kernel

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfRxm.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.